# How to hide menu for mobiles by default? Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logic, hidden

I have a website with **side-bar** menu. Menu is by default visible. If i click **close-btn.** Menu is hidden. That works

I would like make menu by default visible for desktops and by default hidden for mobiles.

```
.side-bar {
  background: #1b1a1b;
  backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  transition-property: left;
}
```

```
.side-bar.non-active {
  left: -250px;
}

.side-bar.active {
  left: 0px;
}
```

The `window.innerWidth < 850` works but i'm not sure if there is something better. 850px i use for **@media queries.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //jquery for toggle sub menus
  $(".sub-btn").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".sub-menu").slideToggle();
    $(this).find(".dropdown").toggleClass("rotate");
  });

  //jquery for expand and collapse the sidebar

  if (window.innerWidth > 850) {
    $(".close-btn").click(function () {
      $(".side-bar").addClass("non-active");
      $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "visible");
    });

    $(".menu-btn").click(function () {
      $(".side-bar").removeClass("non-active");
      $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
  } 
else {
    $(".side-bar").css("left", -250);
    $(".close-btn").click(function () {
      $(".side-bar").addClass("active");
      $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "visible");
    });
    $(".menu-btn").click(function () {
      $(".side-bar").removeClass("active");
      $(".menu-btn").css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
  }
});
```

The issue is propably in `$(".side-bar").css("left", -250);`  because in the DOM i can see it as inline style and after click nothing happen. Only **.menu-btn** disappers.

Is there another way how to set "reverse" logic for mobiles please? Or maybe just easy fix this i hope little bug?

I tried set oposite style for `left: -250px;` to `left:0;` via following logic but without any positiv result..

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```js
if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 850)').matches) { ... }
else { ... }
```

This uses css media query in JavaScript without any frameworks.